# migration to and from aws rds

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, rds

can someone advise me,

1) if I am using aws RDS, how can I seamlessly migrate to own cluster of mysql without downtime and data loss?

2) if I am using own cluster of mysql, how can I switch to RDS without downtime and data loss?

Comment: [Replicating from MySQL to Amazon RDS](http://scale-out-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/replicating-from-mysql-to-amazon-rds.html) describes how one can pretty much migrate to RDS using (the open source) [Tungsten Replicator](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/); however, it appears there is currently no way to migrate out of RDS without downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use replication, then both new and old mysql will sync the data, and you can shutdown the old one after the import completes.

Check this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html

Comment: If it is in production, the sync may never be complete?

Comment: The sync continues when there are changes in the original db. You may use `FLUSH TABLE WITH READ LOCK;` to freeze the original db, then the sync will idle since there are no changes.